# Is it possible to write "in line XX there is an irony" or "in line xx we see an irony/ a hyperbole"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

Written language analysis/rhetorical devices.

Is it possible to write in an analysis:

> in line XX **there is** an irony

or

> In line xx we **see** an irony/a hyperbole?

Doesn't it sound weird?

Comment: 'Irony' is usually used in non-count ways, but I think 'irony' countified in the same way as 'two metaphors ...' is quite acceptable.  While '... there is an example of irony ...' or ' ... Milton uses irony ...' are unarguably acceptable here, both of your examples should be considered fine.

Comment: You just wrote it -- must be possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does sound weird, but it is not wrong.

"Irony" and "hyperbole" are abstract nouns, meaning they have no definite physical representation. Many abstract nouns sound strange with an indefinite article. Examples of said strangeness: "a happiness", "a truthfulness", "a courage", "a dishonesty". However, none of these sound strange with a definite article. Examples: "the happiness", "the truthfulness", "the dishonesty".

Abstract nouns fall into two main categories: countable and uncountable.

In the countable, abstracts nouns can be used with the definite or indefinite article. Examples: "I just told you a truth", "I had a taste of the lollipop, it was nice".

In the uncountable, abstract nouns can be used with no article or the definite article. Examples: "Truth is concrete", "The truth is concrete", "The taste of the lollipop was nice". When you use the definite article with uncountable abstract nouns, you thereby add a sense of specificity.

To preserve your sentence structure, I would rephrase it as "... in line XX we see an example of irony ...", or you could just drop the indefinite article, "... in line XX we see irony".

Comment: I can find plenty of examples of "an irony" in distinguished writers such as [Frank Kermode](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ng139_914YsC&lpg=PA116&ots=cRtDcUSqU7&dq=%22an%20irony%22%20frank%20kermode&pg=PA116#v=onepage&q=%22an%20irony%22%20frank%20kermode&f=false), who wrote in A Sense of an Ending "Order ... is no longer usable except as an irony".